# Diffing the DOM - how to write a unit test that checks that a script doesn't make any user-visible changes to elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, testing, selenium

A JavaScript plugin that I've been writing recently has various failsafes built in that tell either the whole plugin or parts of it to hide itself and die under circumstances where it can't function. For example, let's say that one piece of functionality we offer is automatically generating a popover that shows competitors' prices for an item when the user hovers over it in an online store. Then we'd also have some checks that say that if we don't know any of the competitor's prices, or we can't identify the item, then don't show a popover.

I want to test that functionality-disabling using tests that follow roughly this structure:

1. Load our plugin onto a page where certain functionality ought to be disabled
2. Spoof some user action that would otherwise trigger that functionality
3. ***Assert that no visible changes have been made to the DOM. (i.e. no styling changes to visible elements, no addition or removal of elements unless they have `display:none` on)***

Step #3 is the interesting one, of course. Is there an easy way to write that 'DOM unchanged' test in JavaScript? (Or alternatively in Selenium for Python, which is what I'm using to write my tests - but writing the check in JavaScript is probably more broadly useful since it can then be used in any JavaScript-testing environment.)

---

P.S. A couple of notes to head off the "You're doing it wrong!" crowd:

- Yes, I know that I could just replace step #3 in the test above with a check that the *specific changes* that the plugin would otherwise make have not been made, and I may even decide to do this. But where those specific changes are poorly-specced and liable to change, this catch-all approach could be useful.
- Yes, I also realise that just checking there are no *immediate* visual changes to the DOM when a event that's meant to be effect-free is triggered isn't strictly sufficient to prove that the nothing has broken. It's what'd be best for my current purposes, though. Plus it's interesting and fun even if it turns out not to be useful.

Comment: Another "you're doing it wrong" thing: Test the logic independently from the view, and assert that the `showPopup` method was not *called* - much easier :-). However, your question would still be relevant for testing the view - +1!

Comment: @Bergi Part of the reason I want to take this approach is that most events on the page trigger some functions that have visible effects (and which sometimes need to be suppressed), and others that don't (say, for loading data, or tracking). I'd like to be able to catch a scenario where some programmer who isn't paying attention, or has forgotten about how we've divided up our handler functionality (not like me, of course - I'm perfect and never get confused! :) ) might shove some visual/presentation logic into the data loading or tracking handler, rather than into '`showPopup`'.

Answer (score 4):

Use Mutation observers to detect that no mutations have occurred. You might want to checkout Mutation Summary, a very nice high-level wrapper for mutation observers. Checking that no mutations have occurred could be easy as checking that the returned array has length 0. See https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/.

Comment: +1; this is interesting, and potentially useful to somebody else with the same question. Looking at the small print, though, it won't do for my use case; I'm writing unit tests that I want to work in all browsers - especially IE, since a sizable proportion our bugs are IE-specific. According to the page you've linked to, DOM Mutation Observers are currently only supported by Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: I think you can make "*user-visible changes*" without alerting Mutation Observers - though they will do the task of detecting obvious things like popups. Their only drawback will be the asynchronity, i.e. you don't test for "nothing happens" but "15 seconds without something happened".

Comment: @Bergi, can you give an example of how you could make user-visible changes without the DOM changing? Nothing springs to mind. Also, not sure about your comment about "asynchronicity". You can check for changes at any frequency that suits your fancy, every 50ms if you want, or once when the page is unloaded--whatever.